# How to add days in java?

Tags: java, android, datetime, spinner

I am new in Java. I am trying to add some days depending on the selected item from a spinner but it seems like there is a mistake.

The values in the spinner are: `Today`, `Tomorrow`, `After two days`, `After three days`. Can anybody help me please?

It works perfectly for

Case 0: "Today"; it displays the current date, but for the rest it doesnt work.

Thanks!

```
date_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                rowvalue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        selectedDay = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        selectedDay = c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        selectedDay = c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        selectedDay = c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
                        break;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
});
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" what you mean is "doesn't compile," since if you look at [the documentation for `Calendar#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add-int-int-), it quite clearly says it's a void function -- it has no return value. Your first stop should always be the documentation.

Comment: What is `selectedDay`? You haven't told us and haven't included the declaration. Is it a `String`?

Comment: Please remove the javascript tag from this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire `switch` is unnecessary. You say `case 0` is working, so I guess you want `selectedDay` to be the result of `format`. So remove the `switch` entirely and replace it with:

```
if (position >= 1 && position <= 3) {
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, position);
}
selectedDay = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd").format(c.getTime());
```

`Calendar#add` modifies the calendar instance; then we use that when formatting for `selectedDay`.